# Combine Workbooks and Rename imported worksheet using VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, import

I am trying to import all the XLS files in a particular directory into one workbook. I've tried several sources for the code and the closest I've come is the one below (all the rest complained when closing the imported workbook no matter what i tried).

All I want to do now is take the text from a merged cell (C7 and D7) and rename the new worksheet to that. (there is a carriage return above the name in the cell in case this has any impact. I have no control over the source files as they're produced by an external team).

I'm afraid I have almost no ability with coding of any kind but I can normally futz things reading code from other sources but I stumped here. I've managed to get it to rename it to the source filename but I would prefer to get it from the cell text.

Cheers!

```
Sub Merge2MultiSheets()
Dim wbDst As Workbook
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim strFilename As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    MyPath = "C:\Temp\" ' change to suit
    Set wbDst = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "\*.xls", vbNormal)

    If Len(strFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Do Until strFilename = ""

            Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & "\" & strFilename)

            Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)

            wsSrc.Copy After:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)

            ActiveSheet.Name = wsSrc.Range("C7").Value

            wbSrc.Close False

        strFilename = Dir()

    Loop
    wbDst.Worksheets(1).Delete

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I've worked out that one of my problems is that the cell is actually B7, it was just hidden when i was looking at it (doh!)...so now my only problem is, why is the lowest number source file always the last in the list of tabs? (the source files are reports on server configs named after the server so "server130119.xls" and "server130120.xls" for example).

Answer (score 0):

- I would change this line:
  `ActiveSheet.Name = wsSrc.Range("C7").Value`
  to:
  `wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count).Name = wsSrc.Range("C7")`
  This will ensure you're naming the sheet in your destination workbook, not in your source workbook, which you might end up with by using `ActiveSheet`
- From your question in the comment about the order of your files:
  *(BTW - you should edit your post and put the question in there, comments can get deleted)*
  The order is determined by the "natural" sort order that the files are held in by the OS. I have not found any flags that can be added to the `Dir()` command to sort them on input.
  If you need to process them in name order, I would suggest:

  1. Create a scratch sheet in `wbDst`
  2. Loop through all the files using `Dir()`, putting them in `Range(A1:An)`

     - i.e put the first file name in Range("A1"), the second file name in Range("A2"), etc
  3. Sort `Range(A1:An)` so they are in the desired order
  4. Loop through your now sorted `Range()` to do the actual processing
  5. Delete the scratch sheet from `wbDst` when you're done processing
- For now, comment out:
  `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`
  `Application.EnableEvents = False`
  `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`
  These are great things to have in your code, but not until everything is working properly
- I would suggest changing:
  `If Len(strFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub`
  to
  `If Len(strFilename) > 0 Then`
  `Do Until...`
  `Loop`
  Because, if your initial read of the directory gives you no files, you never get to your clean up code after your loop. At the moment, there's nothing really critical there, but you may modify code in the future, or use this as  model for other code that will require critical clean up, and it's a good habit to be in.